# Нужна ли запятая? Однородные сказуемые или односоставные предложения?

Tags: пунктуация

ИЩИТЕ (?) И ОБРЯЩЕТЕ.

Нужна ли запятая перед И?
В нацкорпусе есть примеры оформления этого выражения и с запятой, и без неё. Отсутствие запятой, впрочем, можно объяснить "устойчивостью" данного выражения.

Меня интересуют все фразы такой структуры. В частности:  "Приходите (?) и узнаете первыми". Я думаю, что это разные односоставные предложения, и запятая нужна.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Полностью с Вами согласна: в данном выражении нет запятой, потому что это фразеологизм со смыслом: добивайтесь своего, ваше упорство будет вознаграждено.

В Евангелии от Матфея (гл. 7, ст. 7—8) сказано (в рус. переводе): «Просите, и дано будет вам; ищите, и найдете; стучите, и отворят вам; ибо всякий просящий получает, и ищущий находит, и стучащему отворят».

На церковно-славянском : «Ищите, и обрящете, толцыте, и отверзется» (ищите, и найдете; стучите, и вам откроют).

В других фразах такой структуры запятая ставится, потому что односоставные предложения разного вида - не два восклицателных, побудительных, вопросительных или односоставных номинативных или безличных.

Одно побудительное, второе повествовательное, а всё невосклицательное. Общей интонации нет.